# Convert a Date in String Format to a datetime.date

Tags: python

I have some strings which come to me in formats like

`29-Jul-2014` or `03-Aug-2015`

What is the easiest way to convert this to a `datetime.date` object?

I can only think to make a dictionary like `d = {'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8, ...}` and then do

`dt = datetime.date(year, d[month], day)`

Is there any other easier way and avoid the creation of this dictionary?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the string to [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('29-Jul-2014', '%d-%b-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 29, 0, 0)
```

Then, use [`datetime.datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) method to convert it to [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('29-Jul-2014', '%d-%b-%Y').date()
datetime.date(2014, 7, 29)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is use `dateutil.parse` module, it lets to parse the common date formats, even if you don't know what it is using currently

Ex:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> 
>>> utc_time     = '2014-07-29T00:00:00'
>>> verbose_time = '29-Jul-2014'
>>> some_locale  = '29/7/14'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(utc_time)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 29, 0, 0)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(verbose_time)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 29, 0, 0)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(some_locale)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 29, 0, 0)
```

Once you have a datetime object, you only should invoke the datetime.date() method